# Facebook app uses a lot of data storage while not logged in

Tags: facebook

I occasionally check my mom's Android phone to see if everything's still running smoothly, just regular maintenance. Today I noticed that the Facebook app on her phone uses 33.46MB of data storage besides the application's size of 27.62MB. Plot twist: she doesn't have a Facebook account and the app on her phone has never been used. Needless to say, the amount of data the app supposedly stores here even though it's not logged in is quite alarming. Does anyone here have any idea what Facebook might be storing and/or tracking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard from various sources that Facebook (and other companies, frankly) do track geo-locations for various purposes, the first and foremost being that they want to serve you ads that you usually see around the web. I've also seen that they really do snoop around a lot (on all of your devices, and yes, even without an account), so geo-locations are probably just the tip of the iceberg.

You might want to check your privacy settings for Facebook just to see what data is being collected. If you're tired of Facebook eating up the storage on your mom's phone, uninstalling should take care of that. Of course, if you want your mom to be out of Facebook's peering eyes, good luck, because you really can never escape Facebook trackers unless you suspend yourself from technology.

Hope this helped.

Comment: To clarify: the "snooping around" happens even without the app being logged into an account? It's to be expected that Facebook will track all kinds of things about you when you're logged in, but doing it on a device where the app is just sitting without an active account is something else altogether. Of course uninstalling would solve the problem, but as is the case with many phones the app came pre-loaded and can't be removed. I think I'll just disable the app through Android's settings. Still, this is pretty sketchy behavior.

Comment: You'd be surprised at what stuff they can capture through a smartphone app. Disabling the app should do the trick, however.

Comment: Alright then, pretty disappointing that this is how far they're willing to go. I guess the mere fact that the app is on your phone means that you've accepted their mobile app's terms, but the fact that it's preinstalled on pretty much every Android phone kinda negates that. I could see this ending up being investigated by the EU if the story got traction, but I guess disabling the app will do for now. Thanks guys!

Comment: Yet another reason to stay away from Facebook, other than it being a time-waster. :D